# Resolving inside a promise catch block

Tags: javascript, promise

I found this in some code. Is there ever a good reason to do this?

```
}).catch(() => {
  resolve();
});
```

I'm curious about whether there are any conceivable ways that this is a good thing to do, but in this case the code I'm reviewing is:

```
function checkExtendedPackage(config, packagePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    extend.check(packagePath)
      .then(() => {
        extend.validate(packagePath, config.allowExtends, config.scope)
          .then(packageToExtend => {
            showOutput.log([{
              type: 'success',
              description: 'validating',
              message: packageToExtend
            }]);
            resolve();
          }).catch(err => {
            reject(err);
          });
      }).catch(() => {
        resolve();
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Looks like a manifestation of the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), so no, probably not.

Comment: We'd need more context, but on the face of it, I'm with @JLRishe. It's *probably* an example of the `new Promise` anti-pattern. (And probably not great error handling, either...)

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have surmised, that's just poorly written code. There's nothing good about the part you initially pointed out and it is indeed an example of the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). It seems to have been written by someone who didn't really understand how to use promises.

It can be improved like this:

```
function checkExtendedPackage(config, packagePath) {
    return extend.check(packagePath)
        .then(() => extend.validate(packagePath, config.allowExtends, config.scope)
            .then(packageToExtend => {
                showOutput.log([{
                    type: 'success',
                    description: 'validating',
                    message: packageToExtend
                }]);
            })
        , () => null);
}
```

As with the original code, this function will return a promise that:

- Will not reject if `extend.check` rejects (resolves to `null` in that case)
- Will reject if `extend.validate` rejects (with the same error)
- Will execute `showOutput.log` with the necessary values if both succeed.

To reduce the nesting and complexity, I would suggest breaking this out into two functions:

```
function validateAndLogExtendedPackage(config, packagePath) {
    return extend.validate(packagePath, config.allowExtends, config.scope)
        .then(packageToExtend => {
            showOutput.log([{
                type: 'success',
                description: 'validating',
                message: packageToExtend
            }]);
        });
}

function checkExtendedPackage(config, packagePath) {
    return extend.check(packagePath)
        .then(
            () => validateAndLogExtendedPackage(config, packagePath),
            () => null
        );
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to use `return new Promise` somewhere for it to be thenable?

Comment: @o-t-w No, as evidenced by the `.then()`s already present in the original code, `extend.check` and `extend.validate` both return thenables. There is no need to redundantly bundle them inside a promise.